# Chess position representation for non-playing software

Tags: chess, representation

I'm looking for an efficient way to represent a chess position.
my "efficiency" criteria are these:

1. requires as little memory as possible
2. given a position representation and a legal move (represented in the usual way, e.g. as in pgn format) it is easy to compute the resulting poisition representation. that is, the function   new_position = compute_position(old_position, move) can be (or is already) implemented in a very efficient way (from a run-time perspective).
3. it is easy to compare two positions to see if they are identical

The reason I try to deviate from standard representations is that my requirements are slightly different. Specifically, I am not trying to develop a chess engine, so move generation and related issues are not required. I only need to follow some existing games, and represent certain positions, and store them in a database.

If there is a software package that that already gives this functionality, that would be great. if you have ideas on how to do it, I'd be happy to develop it :)

Thanks...

Comment: This might not fulfill requirement 1), but FEN does satisfy 2) and 3): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth–Edwards_Notation

Comment: I thought about FEN, it is not memory efficient, but it might do. Is there a free software that implements my point no.2? I didn't find such code, and therefore thought that if I'm going to write it myself, I might just try to find a more efficient way memory-wise.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer some possible solutions that use "as little memory as possible" as per your specification. I know that you can make some of these more compact, but doing so makes it much more difficult to work with.

1. 64 bits: I don't know what kind of information you need to be able to retrieve from the representation, but a technique that fulfills all your given requirements is [Zobrist hashing](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Zobrist+Hashing). It requires very little memory (you can use a 64 bit key and then store 2<sup>32</sup> positions before a collision is expected to occur). It is very easy and efficient to update incrementally (bitwise XOR operations) and of course easy to compare. However, if you need to display the position or retrieve any information about pieces, this leaves you out of luck.
2. 328 bits: you can use a piece list, with each piece (4 bits) located at a square (6 bits). Since there are 32 pieces, and you need to keep track of castling rights (4 bits), en passant file (3 bits), and side to move (1 bit).
3. 468 bits: [bitboard representation](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Bitboards). I know you're not developing a chess engine but this is still a very compact representation. You need 7 bitboards (all white, all black, all queens, all rooks, all bishops, all knights, all pawns), keep track of kings separately (12 bits), and all the other miscellaneous information. Yes this would be a bit of work to implement, but this allows you to do many things not possible in other representations, so this is great if you need to analyze positions.

Comment: The problem with most of these representations is that while they are memory efficient, it is computationally difficult to move from one representation to the next one (based on a legal move). this criterion is, in fact, more important to me.

Comment: btw 2^32 position capacity is too small for any real analysis. Also, I think that using hufmann coding you can reduce full coding to less than 200 bits without loss of inofrmation. the price for this is the complexity of computation.

Comment: @amit Unless you make use of an existing framework, it will always be difficult to make moves. Things like en passant and castling necessitate at least some chess logic, so you'll be hard pressed to find a representation that does not depend on some internal chess representation. That is why I've recommended going directed to these low level representations. Yes I know you can use encoding schemes to further reduce memory footprint if you so wish. And if over 2 billion positions isn't good enough, then use a 128 bit key for Zobrist hashing. Then you'll have 2^64 positions to work with.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free PGN viewer here: http://chesstempo.com/pgn-viewer.html

Regarding the space requirement, you could compress FEN using a compression algorithm of your choice, without losing the ability to check for equality.  Depending how the moves are encoded (g1f3 versus Nf3) you may require a legal move generator for requirement 2).

Comment: I couldn't find what I need in the link provided. I might have given unclear description - so let me clarify. I need a software utility package/library that implement the FEN (or any other representation) manipulation. the main function I need is to compute a new FEN from a given FEN and a legal move. What I see in the link provided is an application that probably knows how to do what I need, but without the code or an API, I can't use it in the software I want to write. Did I miss anything?

Comment: To be honest I didn't find an API either.  Just this morning I found a simple program just designed by two undergrads... perhaps it may help? http://github.com/slepkin/chess